# Assertion Failed: ArrayProxy expects an Array or Ember.ArrayProxy, but you passed object

Tags: ember-cli

This is my code

/******************************************************/

```
import Ember from "ember";

var TodosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

actions: {

createTodo: function(){

  // Get the todo title by the "New Todo" input 
  var title = this.get('newTitle');
  if(!title.trim()){ return; }

  // Create the new Todo model
  var todo = this.store.createRecord('todo', {
    title: title,
    isCompleted: false
  });

  // Clear the 'New Todo' input field
  this.set('newTitle', '');

  // Save the new model
  todo.save();
},

clearCompleted: function(){
  var completed = this.filterBy('isCompleted', true);
  completed.invoke('deleteRecord');
  completed.invoke('save');
}
},

remaining: function() {
return this.filterBy('isCompleted', false).get('length');
}.property('@each.isCompleted'),

inflection: function() {
var remaining = this.get('remaining');
return remaining === 1 ? 'todo' : 'todos';
}.property('remaining'),

hasCompleted: function(){
return this.get('completed') > 0;
}.property('completed'),

completed: function(){
return this.filterBy('isCompleted', true).get('length');
}.property('@each.isCompleted'),

allAreDone: function(key, value) {
if(value === undefined){
  return !!this.get('length') && this.everyProperty('isCompleted', true);
} else {
  this.setEach('isCompleted', value);
  this.invoke('save');
  return value;
}

}.property('@each.isCompleted')

});
export default TodosController;
```

/*******************************************************/

In terminal not showing any error when i run this command

$ ember server

but in browser not showing any thing and console showing this error

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: ArrayProxy expects an Array or
>   Ember.ArrayProxy, but you  passed object

Please suggest me what i m doing wrong, the code is also on github : https://github.com/narayand4/emberjs

thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you getting that error from? Your question isn't specific enough really, and too much code to wade through.

Comment: Getting the same error on my end too (different project).  It appears that no data is being passed in...

Answer (score 11):

The most likely reason for this is that you have a controller which extends from `Ember.ArrayController` while you only return a plain object in the corresponding model.
I had the same issue and changed my controller to extend `Ember.Controller` instead.

Answer (score 4):

In the related route for this controller, your `model` method doesn't return an array, as you've indicated by extending an arrayController.